# get pair-wise sum for the same order

Tags: r

What is the quickest way to get pair-wise sum in R. I read about combn but not sure how to apply it here.

```
    df <- data.frame(dept= c('MENS APPAREL','MOVIES','BEAUTY','HOME','MOVIES','ELECTRONICS'), GMV=c(78.94,23.84,7.6,15, 2,22.7),order_num=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
```

What I have :

```
    dept            TOT_GMV    order_num
    MENS APPAREL    78.94        1
    MOVIES          23.84        1
    BEAUTY          7.6          1
    HOME            15           2
    MOVIES          2            2
    ELECTRONICS     22.7         2
```

What I need :

```
    dept pair                    GMV    order_num
    MENS APPAREL AND BEAUTY      86.54    1
    MENS APPAREL AND MOVIES      102.78   1
    MOVIES & BEAUTY              31.44    1
    HOME AND MOVIES              17       2
    HOME AND ELECTRONICS         37.7     2
    MOVIES AND ELECTRONICS       24.7     2
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able find a solution. Let me know if there is any shorter way of doing this.

```
   df <- data.frame(dept= c('MENS APPAREL','MOVIES','BEAUTY','HOME','MOVIES','ELECTRONICS'), GMV=c(78.94,23.84,7.6,15,  2,22.7),order_num=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))
   df1 <- df
   dd <- merge(df,df1,by=c("order_num"),all.y=TRUE)
   dd1 <- subset(dd,dept.x != dept.y)
   dd2 <- dd1[!duplicated(t(apply(dd1, 1, sort))), ]

   dd2$GMV <- dd2$GMV.x + dd2$GMV.y
   dd2[,c("order_num","dept.x","dept.y","GMV")]

   order_num       dept.x           dept.y       GMV
      1           MENS APPAREL      MOVIES       102.78
      1           MENS APPAREL      BEAUTY       86.54
      1           MOVIES            BEAUTY       31.44
      2           HOME              MOVIES       17.00
      2           HOME              ELECTRONICS  37.70
      2           MOVIES            ELECTRONICS  24.70
```

Answer (score 1):

While the following doesn't return the exact output you're looking for, it does include all possible combinations. Using the 'psych' package you can add two vectors or matrices in an operation analogous to matrix multiplication using '%+%":

```
m <- as.matrix(df[,2])
t <- m%+%t(m)
rownames(t)<- df$dept
colnames(t)<-df$dept    

t
```